# Save keys of HashMap into ArrayList sorted by the HashMaps values in Java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, hashmap

I have a `HashMap<String, Float>` that gets filled with several entries.
I want to save the keys of the HashMap into an `ArrayList<String>`, but sort this ArrayList according to the corresponding values of the HashMap.

Is there a better solution than sorting the HashMap, then using

```
ArrayList<String> sortedKeys = new ArrayList<String>(myHashmap.keySet());
```

By the way I'm not bound to using a HashMap in the first place, but the value sets the order and I don't want swap key and value since the float may change several times.

Comment: I did not understand why would you try to first sort the map, instead of adding it to the list and then sorting it?

Comment: You're right: Sorting the list instead is the better way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can create the array list from the keys first, and then sort:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(myHashMap.keySet());
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(myHashMap::get));
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Very simple and easy to understand code. For my use I had reverse the order, but this can be done easily using `Comparator.comparing(myHashMap::get).reversed()`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the stream API:

```
List<String> sortedKeys = myMap.entrySet()
                       .stream()
                       .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
                       .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                       .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: You are faster ;)

Comment: `Map.Entry.comparingByValue()` a good one I haven't know it existed. +1

Comment: Only one thing if you want to use custom, comparison then there is an overridden method also available which takes a comparator.

Comment: @BilboBaggins Oh yes, absolutely. [comparingByValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByValue-java.util.Comparator-). thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This code solved my problem, but I preferred the answer by Sweeper, because it didn't involve using a stream and seemed a little bit simpler to understand.

Comment: @ChristophH. you're more than welcome and sure, pick whichever answer you prefer.  this is the good part of having several valid answers. it allows you to pick the one you feel is most readable, efficient or whatever criteria you're seeking. :)